# Oracle Golden Gate User Exit - EXIT_CALL_PROCESS_RECORD not passed

Tags: c++, database, oracle, oracle-golden-gate

I have problem with `create custom User Exit` in Oracle Golden Gate.
I need to connect to the stream of changes during database replication and create JSON string of this changes.

At this moment I have a fully working database replication from Oracle 12c to Oracle 12c, I created a simple library that sends to the logs events sended by GoldenGate extract.

Everything works to this moment, I need to catch `EXIT_CALL_PROCESS_RECORD` because this type of event contains table names, columns and data ([Exit Call Types](http://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/ns1221/gg-nsk/GNSRF/GUID-551A1D77-A710-4E5B-B9E9-7D74BE12236D.htm#GNSRF720))
But for some reason this event doesn't appear, in report file i have only three types of events:

```
EXIT_CALL_CHECKPOINT
EXIT_CALL_BEGIN_TRANS
EXIT_CALL_END_TRANS
```

How I can invoke `EXIT_CALL_PROCESS_RECORD` call type?

This is my current configuration and Exit User Source code:

**Data miner:**

```
EXTRACT REXT1
EXTTRAIL ./dirdat/Z1
TRANLOGOPTIONS DBLOGREADER
GETUPDATEBEFORES
FETCHOPTIONS FETCHPKUPDATECOLS
USERID GGUSER@192.168.99.100:32774/xe , PASSWORD GGUSER
TABLE ERP.*;
```

**Data pump:**

```
EXTRACT REXT2
DISCARDFILE ./dirrpt/eqalap.dsc, PURGE
RMTHOST 127.0.0.1, MGRPORT 7851, COMPRESS
RMTTRAIL ./dirdat/Z2
CUSEREXIT hello.so CUSEREXIT, INCLUDEUPDATEBEFORES
NOPASSTHRU
MAP ERP.*, TARGET HRMS.*;
```

**Replicat:**

```
replicat RREP1
setenv (NLS_LANG = AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252)
useridalias GGTARGETADMIN domain OGG
handlecollisions
assumetargetdefs
CUSEREXIT hello.so CUSEREXIT, INCLUDEUPDATEBEFORES
map HRMS.* target HRMS.* ;
```

**User Exit Source code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "usrdecs.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" {
    void ERCALLBACK(ercallback_function_codes function_code, void *buf, short *presult_code);
    void call_callback(ercallback_function_codes function_code, void *buf, short *result_code);
    void output_msg(char *msg, ...);
    void CUSEREXIT(exit_call_type_def exit_call_type, exit_result_def *exit_call_result, exit_params_def *exit_params);
}

void ERCALLBACK(ercallback_function_codes function_code, void *buf, short *presult_code);
void call_callback(ercallback_function_codes function_code, void *buf, short *result_code);
void CUSEREXIT(exit_call_type_def exit_call_type, exit_result_def *exit_call_result, exit_params_def *exit_params);

void call_callback(ercallback_function_codes function_code, void *buf, short *result_code) {
    ERCALLBACK(function_code, buf, result_code);
}

void output_msg(char *msg, ...) {
    short result_code;
    char temp_msg[1000];

    va_list args;

    vsprintf(temp_msg, msg, args);
    call_callback(OUTPUT_MESSAGE_TO_REPORT, temp_msg, &result_code);
}

void CUSEREXIT(exit_call_type_def exit_call_type, exit_result_def *exit_call_result, exit_params_def *exit_params) {
    short result_code;

    switch (exit_call_type) {
    case EXIT_CALL_START:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_START\n", result_code);
        break;
    case EXIT_CALL_BEGIN_TRANS:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_BEGIN_TRANS\n", result_code);
        break;
    case EXIT_CALL_PROCESS_RECORD:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_PROCESS_RECORD\n", result_code);
        break;
    case EXIT_CALL_DISCARD_ASCII_RECORD:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_DISCARD_ASCII_RECORD\n", result_code);
        break;
    case EXIT_CALL_DISCARD_RECORD:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_DISCARD_RECORD\n", result_code);
        break;
    case EXIT_CALL_END_TRANS:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_END_TRANS\n", result_code);
        break;
    case EXIT_CALL_CHECKPOINT:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_CHECKPOINT\n", result_code);
        break;
    case EXIT_CALL_PROCESS_MARKER:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_PROCESS_MARKER\n", result_code);
        break;
    case EXIT_CALL_STOP:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_STOP\n", result_code);
        break;
    case EXIT_CALL_DISCARD_TRANS_RECORD:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_DISCARD_TRANS_RECORD\n", result_code);
        break;
    case EXIT_CALL_ABORT_TRANS:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_ABORT_TRANS\n", result_code);
        break;
    case EXIT_CALL_EVENT_RECORD:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_EVENT_RECORD\n", result_code);
        break;
    case EXIT_CALL_FATAL_ERROR:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_FATAL_ERROR\n", result_code);
        break;
    default:
        output_msg((char*)"default\n", result_code);
        break;
    }

    *exit_call_result = EXIT_OK_VAL;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code itself seems to be correct. If you compile the same code in C rather than in C++ - it works correctly. You must submit a SR request to Oracle - this might be a bug.

```
#include <stdio.h>

  #if defined(__linux__)
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <stdarg.h>
    #define I64_FMT  "%Ld"
  #endif

  #if defined(__MVS__)
    #include <stdarg.h>
    #include <varargs.h>
    #include <inttypes.h>
    #define I64_FMT  "%lld"
  #endif

  #if !defined(__MVS__) && !defined(__linux__)
    #include <stdarg.h>
    #define I64_FMT  "%lld"
  #endif

   #include <string.h>
  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <ctype.h>

#include "usrdecs.h"

void call_callback(ercallback_function_codes function_code, void *buf, short *result_code) {
    ERCALLBACK(function_code, buf, result_code);
}

void output_msg(char *msg, ...) {
    short result_code;
    char temp_msg[1000];

    va_list args;

    vsprintf(temp_msg, msg, args);
    call_callback(OUTPUT_MESSAGE_TO_REPORT, temp_msg, &result_code);
}

void CUSEREXIT(exit_call_type_def exit_call_type, exit_result_def *exit_call_result, exit_params_def *exit_params) {
    short result_code;

    switch (exit_call_type) {
    case EXIT_CALL_START:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_START\n", result_code);
        break;
    case EXIT_CALL_BEGIN_TRANS:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_BEGIN_TRANS\n", result_code);
        break;
    case EXIT_CALL_PROCESS_RECORD:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_PROCESS_RECORD\n", result_code);
        break;
    case EXIT_CALL_DISCARD_ASCII_RECORD:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_DISCARD_ASCII_RECORD\n", result_code);
        break;
    case EXIT_CALL_DISCARD_RECORD:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_DISCARD_RECORD\n", result_code);
        break;
    case EXIT_CALL_END_TRANS:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_END_TRANS\n", result_code);
        break;
    case EXIT_CALL_CHECKPOINT:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_CHECKPOINT\n", result_code);
        break;
    case EXIT_CALL_PROCESS_MARKER:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_PROCESS_MARKER\n", result_code);
        break;
    case EXIT_CALL_STOP:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_STOP\n", result_code);
        break;
    case EXIT_CALL_DISCARD_TRANS_RECORD:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_DISCARD_TRANS_RECORD\n", result_code);
        break;
    case EXIT_CALL_ABORT_TRANS:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_ABORT_TRANS\n", result_code);
        break;
    case EXIT_CALL_EVENT_RECORD:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_EVENT_RECORD\n", result_code);
        break;
    case EXIT_CALL_FATAL_ERROR:
        output_msg((char*)"EXIT_CALL_FATAL_ERROR\n", result_code);
        break;
    default:
        output_msg((char*)"default\n", result_code);
        break;
    }

    *exit_call_result = EXIT_OK_VAL;
}
```

Comment: After compiling in C everything works great, thank you very much.